# How prove the lines $AD,BE,CF$ are concurrent

Tags: geometry

**Question:**

> Let $ABCDEF$ be a convex hexagon which has no parallel sides and in which $$AB=DE,BC=EF,CD=FA$$
>
> and $$\angle A-\angle D=\angle E-\angle B=\angle C-\angle F$$
> Show that the lines $AD,BE,CF$ are concurrent.
> [image]

This is a problem my friends asked me. I found something similar in the [2011 USAMO](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/2011_USAMO_Problems/Problem_3), as [discussed on the Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2254803&sid=22d1a497cec7d72412d71cd77dc6c378#p2254803)

But my problem is not the same, and I can't solve it. Maybe [Ceva's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem) can be of use.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the hexagon supposed to be non-convex? Your picture showed a convex one.

Comment: oh,Thank you,my problem is convex hexagon

Comment: Does such a hexagon exist? When I try sketching one in GeoGebra, I can only seem to close the loop when $\angle A = \angle D$, $\angle B = \angle E$, $\angle C = \angle F$, in which case opposite edges are parallel, violating your condition.

Comment: Hello,I have  edit:the  source of the posted questions, this is  In 2014 the Chinese national team training

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a problem in notation. 
Let we fix $A,F,E,D$ and assume that $\widehat{D}-\widehat{A}=\delta.$
Let $P$ be the symmetric of $F$ with respect to the midpoint of $AD$. Then:
$$ C = D+(P-D)e^{i\delta}, $$
but $A+D=P+F$ gives:
$$ C = D+(A-F)e^{i\delta}. \tag{1}$$
In a similar fashion, let $Q$ be the symmetric of $E$ with respect to the midpoint of $FC$. We have:
$$ B = C+(Q-C)e^{i\delta}, $$
but $Q+E=C+F$ gives:
$$ B = C + (F-E)e^{i\delta} = D + (A-E)e^{i\delta}. \tag{2}$$
Again, let $R$ be the symmetric of $D$ with respect to the midpoint of $BE$. We have:
$$ A = B+(R-B)e^{i\delta}, $$
but $D+R=E+B$ gives:
$$ A = B + (E-D)e^{i\delta} = D + (A-D)e^{i\delta},\tag{3} $$
so $(A-D)=(A-D)e^{i\delta}$ follows and we have $\delta=0$. This implies that the hexagon has parallel opposite sides and the lines $AD,BE,CF$ meet in their common midpoint.

Comment: It's Nice! Thank you,

Comment: So, the question's requirement that the hexagon "has no parallel sides" cannot be met. That a hexagon whose opposite edges are congruent and parallel has "long" diagonals that meet at a common midpoint is essentially demonstrated [by the figure in this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/452121/409), where the hexagon is taken as $A^\prime MB^\prime KC^\prime N$.