# prove the perpendiculars from the three excenters to the corresponding sides concur at the reflection of the incenter in the circumcenter

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

> Let ABC be a triangle. Let $I_A,I_B,I_C,R_A,R_B,R_C$ be the A-, B-, and C- excenters and corresponding radii of ABC, let $O'$ be the circumcenter of $I_AI_BI_C,$ and let $R$ be the circumradius of $ABC.$

1. Prove the perpendiculars from the three excenters to the corresponding sides of ABC concur at the reflection of the incenter $I$ of ABC in the circumcenter $O$ of ABC.
2. Prove that $O' A_a = 2R - R_A,$ where $A_a = O'I_A \cap BC.$

I think a related proof is that the nine point circle of the excentral triangle of ABC is centered at the midpoint between $I$, its orthocenter, and $O',$ its circumcenter. For instance, there are some proofs of this fact [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451979/prove-that-the-centre-of-the-nine-point-circle-lies-on-the-midpoint-of-the-euler). Symmetry should be useful; it suffices to show that $I_A O'$ is perpendicular to $BC$.

I'm pretty sure the second result applies symmetrically to the other two sides of ABC. As for how to approach this problem, a seemingly simple case would be when ABC is an equilateral triangle. Then intuitively I think all the exradii are equal to each other and the circumcenter of $I_AI_BI_C$ equals $O$. Also, I think $I_AI_BI_C$ is an equilateral triangle. The law of sines or the law of cosines might be useful for computing lengths and Ceva's theorem might be useful for problem 1.

Below is a picture that could help illustrate the two problems.
[image]

> Source: some university level geometry notes from 2013.

Comment: Please state explicitly a question, then give details on the own progress to answer it - best doing this in a manner that shares the already made progress in a way that it is precise and reusable. A picture is in such cases almost a must. And some more context would be also relevant: Which is the source of the problem (or of a related problem), why is it important, and so on. Please try to match as much as possible the "How to ask a good question?" hints from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question ...

Comment: @dan_fulea thanks. The reason why I've posted 2 questions instead of just one is because the second question is likely closely related to the first question and I'd need to basically copy a lot of the definitions if I wanted to make a separate post for the second question. Though I could do this if you prefer it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the homothety at $I$ mapping $M$ to $I_a$. It maps $O$ to $I''$, but $OM||I''I_a$ and $OM\perp BC$. To show $I''=O'$, it suffices to show that $O'I_a\perp BC$ because $I,O,I'$ are collinear (Euler Line of $I_aI_bI_c$). This is a basic fact about a general triangle, and is a basic angle chase. In the other problem you posted I showed that $O'I_a=2R$ since the homothety has scale factor $2$, from which the second part of the problem follows immediately.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on why $OM\perp BC $ implies $I'' =O'$? Also, I'm not sure how your answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546086/prove-that-m-and-m-are-antipodal-on-the-circumcircle-and-mm-is-the-perpe)  shows $O'I_a = 2R.$

Comment: For the $O'I_a=2R$, note that the homothety has scale factor $2$, so $O'I_a=2OM=2R$. For the other part, I'll edit into the answer because it's nontrivial.